# qmake QT 4.6 application with no XCode project in Mac OS X?

Tags: xcode, qt, qt4, qmake

I've downloaded the source for KardsGT, which is written for I think QT 4.6.x onto my Mac OS X 10.6.8 system.

Since KardsGT is not written specifically for Mac OS X (it was meant for GNU/Linux), there is no associated XCode files, etc. When I run qmake on the source, I get lots of error like

WARNING: Ignored (not found) '/src/kardsgt-0.7.1/src/players/players-debug.xcodeproj'

It seems that qmake is thinking I am using XCode for this project? How do I correct this so the code will compile? (I've tried qmake -unix but that didn't change the results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need Xcode to compile a Qt program. Just run

```
$ qmake -config release
$ make clean
$ make
```

and you should be good to go (if the sources do not use any Linux-specific stuff).

Comment: also you could add -spec macx-g++ to generate Makefile and use make instead of xcode

Comment: Kamil's solution works. I tried qmake -config release when trying to compile qcachegrind, and got the same errors, whereas qmake -spec macx-g++ works properly.